# Text input field doesn't work in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari, safari6

I can't figure out why, but for some reason my text input fields don't work in safari (any version, as far as I can tell). Users can't type into the text boxes. I'm at a loss here, since it works in every other browser (Including IE6, although it looks awful). Here's the live site: [enter link description here](http://www.spice-club.tk/login)

Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is being applied:

`-webkit-user-select: none;` in `forms.css`, line 11.

Comment: I forgot about that. I probably would have noticed if Chrome still respected those rules. Thank you.